# White Line across UIToolbar when table view present

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitoolbar

I have a programmatically created UIToolbar in a couple of views.  In my view that has a table present, there is a white line across the middle of the toolbar, that appears to be where the border of the table cell would be.  Is there a way to get rid of this line?

Here's a screen shot:

[image: iphone table with white bar]

Here's the code I'm using to create the toolbar shown:

```
- (void) createToolbarItems {
UIBarButtonItemStyle style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;

UIImage *addWishImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-addwish-off.png"];
UIButton *addBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[addBtn setImage:addWishImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
addBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, addWishImg.size.width, addWishImg.size.height);
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:addBtn];
[addButton setTarget:self];
[addButton setAction:@selector(addWish)];
addButton.style = style;

UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                          target:nil
                                                                          action:nil];
flexItem.style = style;

UIImage *emailImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-mail-off.png"];
UIButton *emailBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[emailBtn setImage:emailImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
emailBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, emailImg.size.width, emailImg.size.height);
UIBarButtonItem *emailButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:emailBtn];
[emailButton setTarget:self];
[emailButton setAction:@selector(addWish)];
emailButton.style = style;

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: addButton, flexItem, emailButton, nil];
[self.toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];

[addButton release];
[flexItem release];
[emailButton release];
```

}

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

…

// create the UIToolbar at the bottom of the view controller
toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

// size up the toolbar and set its frame
[toolbar sizeToFit];
CGFloat toolbarHeight = [toolbar frame].size.height;
NSLog(@"%f", toolbarHeight);
CGRect mainViewBounds = self.view.bounds;
[toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(mainViewBounds),
                             CGRectGetMinY(mainViewBounds) + CGRectGetHeight(mainViewBounds) - (toolbarHeight * 2.0) + 2.0,
                             CGRectGetWidth(mainViewBounds),
                             toolbarHeight)];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

[self createToolbarItems];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the table separator style to None gets rid of this problem.

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check whether your tableView is overlapping the toolbar? Otherwise, can't see any apparent issues. Set a background color to your tableview to see if that is the case. Or just reduce the tableview's height a bit to see if that resolves the issue

Comment: I have a simlar view on another controller (table with a toolbar) and am not experiencing this issue.